# Chatterbot from chatterbot import ChatBot ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'chatterbot'

Tags: python, pip, chatterbot

```
from chatterbot import ChatBot
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'chatterbot'
```

Já atualizei a biblioteca `chatterbot` e o `pip`, também já alterei o endereço do *path* para `C:\Users\Vinic\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts` e `C:\Users\Vinic\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37` que é uma versão mais recente do Python 3.7.3 e o código do `chatterbot` é bem básico pois não consigo avançar disso

```
from chatterbot import ChatBot

bot = ChatBot(
    'Terminal',
    storage_adapter='chatterbot.storage.MongoDatabaseAdapter',
    logic_adapters=[
        'chatterbot.logic.BestMatch'
    ],
    database_uri='mongodb://localhost:27017/chatterbot-database'
)

print('Type something to begin...')

while True:
    try:
        user_input = input()

        bot_response = bot.get_response(user_input)

        print(bot_response)

    # Press ctrl-c or ctrl-d on the keyboard to exit
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, EOFError, SystemExit):
        break
```

Comment: Como fez a instalação? Qual o resultado de `pip show chatterbot`?

Comment: De uma lida no `requirements.txt` do `chatterbot` e verifique se seu sistema tem todas as dependências instaladas.

Comment: Anderson Carlos Woss e Augusto Vasques consegui resolver o problema, não tinha atualizado o pip nem o chatterbot, estava tentando atualizar o chatterbot primeiro antes do pip.....

Comment: Só que agora estou com o seguinte problema 'database_url='C:\Users\Vinic\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\python\db.sqlite3' esta dando erro de (Unicode error) nesse caracter =

Comment: Estou usando o IDLE 3.7.3